Постановка пунктуации в сокращенных предложениях
Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания:
Стоимость: 2000 рублей. Для Вас - бесплатно.

Лишь цена может быть назначена и снижена до нуля как величина рыночная. Стоимость же продукта есть цифра расчётная (вероятная), и фактическая. Она отражает затраты.
Об остальном: личное обращение здесь не кажется очевидным (т.е. вы — со строчной); тире должно выглядеть, как тире (не дефис). И ещё... В оглашение цены товара, и тут же, — в объявлении его подарком, есть доля двусмысленности. Её нельзя допустить.
Как вариант. Цена: 2000 рублей. (Торг приветствуется).
